# htaccess - rewrite URL ending with specific string and capturing the unique part

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to feed several URLs into a single php file that will handle the contents of the page, the URLs are like

```
domain.com/fashion-registration
domain.com/singing-registration
```

I want to capture URLs ending with `-registration` and feed `fashion` or `singing` into the page but it doesn't seem to be working. This is what I tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$-registration category.php?link=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)-registration/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /category.php?link=%1 [NE,NC,L]
```

OR you could try following too, one without RewriteCond.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)-registration/?$ /category.php?link=$1 [NE,NC,L]
```

***Problem in OP's attempt:*** Since you have used `^(.*)$` and after that you are using `-registration` in your regex that's why your regex is NEVER going to match `-registration`

Comment: @VeeK, I tested it before posting it works fine for me, see this `curl -IL "http://localhost:80/fashion-registration"` -----> `Location: http://localhost/category.php?link=fashion`, it works for me, let me know on same.

Comment: My site is not in the root of localhost. I fixed it with `RewriteBase`. There's one other issue if I may. It doesn't work if a url has a `-` in it. For example, `/fashion-show-registration`. Can you solve this?